# Javascript HTTP Get doesn't return an XML?

Tags: javascript, xml, http, get, request

I made a little REST API that return a result in xml format after accessing http://localhost/rest/test

I'm trying to access the API with javacscript

```
 xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
```

But when I display what's in the response text by

```
alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

or even doing

```
var info = eval ( "(" + xmlHttp.responseText + ")" );
alert(local)
```

It does no display an `<xml>..<xml>` like it should (if i accces the api from a browser it returns me an xml) But it returns me instead an html table?

like

```
<thread>
<tr> etc...
</thread>
```

How can i force let it stay in xml ?

Thanks

Comment: http://localhost/rest/test <- link does not work!

Answer (score 0):

you want to eval an xml string in javascript? are you sure you are not expecting json?

xml files can be displayed as tables by browsers if styles are associated with them.

```
It does no display an .. like it should
```

what do you mean by that? that doesnt look like valid xml to me.

however i can tell you that your documents dont get magically transformed. i am almost certain the error is on your side.

i can give you the tip not to write xml code yourself. dont do something like `echo '<node attribute="'.$val,"'...`

There are very good container classes like DomDocument that you can use to generate your structure and that you can print as valid xml.

also make sure your headers are correct. This shouldnt be a proflem, when you deal with the body from the document as a string, but it can be in other situations.

Comment: Sorry maybe I haven't explained the problem very well.
I coded a little rest API (it's really simple if a test it using a browser something like http://localhost/myrestApi/test it returns
<xml> <node>hello</node></xml> for example)

But if I do the get request in javascript (code in the first thread) if a just display the result. it is not an xml? it convert it automatically in a html table